# Getting illegal characters in get_browser() method run in php

Tags: php, character-encoding, browscap

From the [manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) I am running a simple code to fetch browser info using `get_browser()` method.

Code in the manuals -

[image: code_in_manuals]

Code I am running(almost same/i tried by removing `echo "<pre>";` but no effect) -

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($browser);
?>
```

This is the `error/illegal characters` I am getting at `browser_name_regex` -

[image: get_browser_error]

I also tried this UTF 8 encoding for characters, but problem still persist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test browser</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($browser);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong and where to look for the solution?

One thing more to ask, in the same doc -

> Attempts to determine the capabilities of the user's browser, by
>   looking up the browser's information in the browscap.ini file.

Where do I find this `browscap.ini` in my system I am using `Windows 7`...although I am not very sure if it is related with this problem or not.

Comment: If you want to extract Browser Name then you can only use `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`.

Comment: @NullVoid thx bro I already know that ..but it is not what i was looking for...I am looking for the CURE not for the PREVENTION :)

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you found browscap.in file in your given path then specify that absolute path `C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini` in your php.ini file like

I have in my local setup (php.ini), actually I have generated browscap file from other function and then pasted it in file and then found correct output.

```
[browscap]
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini
browscap = D:\ZendServer\etc\browscap.ini
```

you can specify your absolute path like

```
[browscap]
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini
browscap = C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini
```

and code to check

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($browser);die;
```

Comment: bro if thr is mismatching in file then NO DATA should be reflected ..but I am getting the data..ONLY problem in browser_name_regex ....rest ALL working fine as u can chk in screenshot

Comment: Then there should be some other issue because I am getting perfect infor without issue of character encoding.

Comment: You can try with this `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); `

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been asked at [PHP - get_browser() results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392256/php-get-browser-results)

Based on the information there and the information found at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=612364 which explains the bug more throughly, i've created some lines of code which solves the problem.

I've posted my answer both here and there.

Code:

```
if (function_exists('get_browser') && ini_get('browscap')) {
    $browser_info = get_browser(null, true);
    if (function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) $browser_info['browser_name_regex'] = mb_convert_encoding($browser_info['browser_name_regex'], "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");
    print_r($browser_info);
}
```